# Zend 1.12 Db creating query

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I want to rewrite my query.
I'm selecting all rows `where id IN(id1, id2, id3, ...)` but i want to change it.
is it possible to use this `$query` array as where in my query?

```
$id = array(id1, id2, id3 ...);
$query = array("id = ?" => $id);
$select = $this->select()->where($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yes* this is possible to use *array* in where.

Consider Following **updated** code:

```
$id = array(1,2,3,4);
$select = $this->select()->where("id IN (?)", $id);
```

Comment: Yeah but I got error "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'", and I thougth that I should do this on the other way :C

Comment: Check out UPdated answer @user3845113. Try this one

Comment: ok I solved my problem. I had to specify type of variable:
$select = $this->select()->where("id IN (?)", $id, 'INT');

Thank you for your help!